# TextBox doesn't fire TextChanged Event on IE 8, AutoPostback is true

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, textbox

I have the same thing, there are many TextBoxes with the event TextChanged set and with 
AutoPostback = true, and works in all browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox 3.6) except in IE 8, IE 6/7 I didn't test.

I don't want to put the onblur event in all my TextBoxs because there are many pages with many TextBox that use this event.

Description

I'm using a masterPage,

in the aspx i have

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCnpj" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Width="200px"
    onkeyup="Mascara(this,Cnpj)" onkeydown="Mascara(this,Cnpj)" MaxLength="18"
    AutoPostBack="true" ValidationGroup="txtCnpj"
    OnTextChanged="txtCnpj_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

in the aspx.cs

```
 protected void txtCnpj_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (CredorInvestimento.GetCredorInvestimento(txtCnpj.Text) != null)
        {
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = "";
            ((TextBox)sender).Focus();
            rfvCnpj.ErrorMessage = "Duplicado";
            Page.Validate(txtCnpj.ID);
        }
        else
            txtNome.Focus();
    }
```

Thanks!

ps: I really doesn't like of asp.net I spend more time fixing errors than developing new functions.

ps: sorry for my english.

ps: if i remove the onkeydown and onkeyup events the textchanged fire in IE, but i realy this events too.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `Mascara()`?

Comment: agreed - I'm guessing their is possibly an error in Mascara() that prevents the postback event from occurring in IE. Have you tried removing the onKeyDown and onKeyUp events and seeing if the postback works?

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that the OnTextChanged event only fires when you leave the textbox? If you want to fire the event in KeyUp, you can add a __doPostBack to the markup and remove the autopostback.

You can use this way.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCnpj" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Width="200px"
    onkeyup="Mascara(this,Cnpj); _doPostBack('txtCnpj', '');" 
    MaxLength="18" ValidationGroup="txtCnpj"
    OnTextChanged="txtCnpj_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or you can also use

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCnpj" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Width="200px"
        MaxLength="18" ValidationGroup="txtCnpj"
        OnTextChanged="txtCnpj_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

$('[id$="txtCnpj"]').on('keypress', function () {
    Mascara(this, Cnpj);
})
```